# Ignore strings which do not completely match regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to return all recipients of an email using regex. For example:

```
Date: Wed, 6 Dec 2000 02:03:00 -0800 (PST)
From: donald.herrick@enron.com
To: brianherrick@email.msn.com, herriceu2@tdprs.state.tx.us, 
    robertherrick@bankunited.com, kristi.demaiolo@enron.com, 
    suresh.raghavan@enron.com, harry.arora@enron.com
Subject: FW: If Santa Answered his mail...
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-From: Donald W Herrick
X-To: brianherrick@email.msn.com, HERRICEU2@tdprs.state.tx.us, RobertHerrick@bankunited.com, Kristi Demaiolo, Suresh Raghavan, Harry Arora
X-cc: 
X-bcc:
```

Should return (from the "To: " line) *brianherrick@email.msn.com, herriceu2@tdprs.state.tx.us, robertherrick@bankunited.com, kristi.demaiolo@enron.com, suresh.raghavan@enron.com, harry.arora@enron.com*

but **not** (from the "X-To: " line) *brianherrick@email.msn.com, HERRICEU2@tdprs.state.tx.us, RobertHerrick@bankunited.com* .

My current regex is `re.findall([To:\s][\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+, text)` which returns everything from the "To:", "X-To: " and "From: " line.

**My questions:**

1. Why is the email address on the "From: " line also returned? It
   doesn't match the `[To:\s]` part of the regex?!
2. How can I ensure that only email addresses which follow "To: " are
   returned? (That is, how do I exclude email addresses following
   "X-To: "? I think that you can use lookahead assertions for this but I am not sure how to do this?

Comment: `[To:\s]` does **not** do what you think it does. `'o:  TT TTTo oT:::'` matches too, as `[....]` models a *set* of characters, not a sequence. Provided you have a `*` or `+` after the set, otherwise it matches just *one character*.

Comment: In other words, your current expression matches `T.----.whoopee@foobar` just because it starts with one of `T`, `o`, `:` or a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood what a character class does; your pattern matches *anywhere* a string contains a `T`, `o`, `:` or whitespace character.

That's because `[To:\s]` models a *character class*, any one character in the set will match. This is why your `From:` line matches; the space between `:` and `d` suffices here.

If you need to validate the whole header name, anchor your match to the start of lines with `^`, but remove that character class:

```
r'^To:\s+[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+'
```

Now the `To:` part only matches if at the start of a line, provided you use the `re.MULTILINE` flag:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '''\
... Date: Wed, 6 Dec 2000 02:03:00 -0800 (PST)
... From: donald.herrick@enron.com
... To: brianherrick@email.msn.com, herriceu2@tdprs.state.tx.us, 
...     robertherrick@bankunited.com, kristi.demaiolo@enron.com, 
...     suresh.raghavan@enron.com, harry.arora@enron.com
... Subject: FW: If Santa Answered his mail...
... Mime-Version: 1.0
... Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
... Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
... X-From: Donald W Herrick
... X-To: brianherrick@email.msn.com, HERRICEU2@tdprs.state.tx.us, RobertHerrick@bankunited.com, Kristi Demaiolo, Suresh Raghavan, Harry Arora
... X-cc: 
... X-bcc: 
... '''
>>> re.findall(r'^To:\s+[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', text)
[]
>>> re.findall(r'^To:\s+[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', text, flags=re.M)
['To: brianherrick@email.msn.com']
```

This can only ever match the first email address, and only if it doesn't include anything like a full name (`Brian Herrick <brianherrick@email.msn.com>`, for example).

You'd have to match the whole *header* instead:

```
re.findall(r'^To:\s+((?:.*(?:\n[ \t]+)?)*)', text, flags=re.M)
```

This matches the `To:` header followed by any number of header continuation lines (starting with whitespace):

```
>>> re.findall(r'^To:\s+((?:.*(?:\n[ \t]+)?)*)', text, flags=re.M)
['brianherrick@email.msn.com, herriceu2@tdprs.state.tx.us, \n    robertherrick@bankunited.com, kristi.demaiolo@enron.com, \n    suresh.raghavan@enron.com, harry.arora@enron.com']
```

and you'd have to extract email addresses separately from that.

Personally, I'd be looking into the [`email` package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html) instead, it would make it much easier to grab headers with that:

```
import email

message = email.message_from_string(text)
to_headers = message.get_all('to')
addresses = email.utils.getaddresses(to_headers)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import email
>>> m = email.message_from_string(text)
>>> m.get_all('to')
['brianherrick@email.msn.com, herriceu2@tdprs.state.tx.us, \n    robertherrick@bankunited.com, kristi.demaiolo@enron.com, \n    suresh.raghavan@enron.com, harry.arora@enron.com']
>>> email.utils.getaddresses(m.get_all('to'))
[('', 'brianherrick@email.msn.com'), ('', 'herriceu2@tdprs.state.tx.us'), ('', 'robertherrick@bankunited.com'), ('', 'kristi.demaiolo@enron.com'), ('', 'suresh.raghavan@enron.com'), ('', 'harry.arora@enron.com')]
```

Now you have all the email addresses.

The [`email.utils.getaddresses()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.getaddresses) can also be applied when using the regular expression:

```
>>> email.utils.getaddresses(re.findall(r'^To:\s+((?:.*(?:\n[ \t]+)?)*)', text, flags=re.M))
[('', 'brianherrick@email.msn.com'), ('', 'herriceu2@tdprs.state.tx.us'), ('', 'robertherrick@bankunited.com'), ('', 'kristi.demaiolo@enron.com'), ('', 'suresh.raghavan@enron.com'), ('', 'harry.arora@enron.com')]
```

Comment: Thanx. I will look into the email package, but I don't know if that is what I am looking for as I am building a generic parser for txt files (which happen to contain emails for this example)
The reason I have `[To:\s]` in my expression is that when I had `To:\s` and the multiline flag it only returned the first email address (brianherrick@email.msn.com), where as I need to return all matches to `[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+` which appear after "To: ", but not after "X-To: ". Is that possible?

Comment: @user3797035: you can only match *the whole header*, not individual email addresses then.

Comment: @user3797035: added more detail on how to use a regular expression to extract all the `To:` headers, and how to parse those into email addresses using the `email.utils` package.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to @MartijnPieters 's answer, regex may not be the right tool for the JOB. To parse an email message, it is recommended to use [email.parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html)

```
>>> from email.parser import Parser
>>> headers = Parser().parsestr(email_str)
>>> pprint.pprint(map(str.strip, headers['to'].split()))
['brianherrick@email.msn.com,',
 'herriceu2@tdprs.state.tx.us,',
 'robertherrick@bankunited.com,',
 'kristi.demaiolo@enron.com,',
 'suresh.raghavan@enron.com,',
 'harry.arora@enron.com']
```

Comment: Don't use splitting and stripping; there is a much better method in the `email.utils` package for parsing email addresses in a `To` header: https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.getaddresses

Answer (score 0):

**`regex` module: infinite lookbehind and other features**

If you want to use regex, I suggest you use the outstanding [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) instead of `re`. This regex will return all matches:

```
(?<=(?<!X\S+)To:\s*(?:[^@\s]+@[^\,\s]+,\s*)*?)[^@\s]+@[^\,\s]+
```

**Sample Code**

I tested this in Python 3.4.

```
import regex
subject = """Date: Wed, 6 Dec 2000 02:03:00 -0800 (PST)
From: donald.herrick@enron.com
To: brianherrick@email.msn.com, herriceu2@tdprs.state.tx.us, 
    robertherrick@bankunited.com, kristi.demaiolo@enron.com, 
    suresh.raghavan@enron.com, harry.arora@enron.com
Subject: FW: If Santa Answered his mail...
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-From: Donald W Herrick
X-To: brianherrick@email.msn.com, HERRICEU2@tdprs.state.tx.us, RobertHerrick@bankunited.com, Kristi Demaiolo, Suresh Raghavan, Harry Arora
X-cc: 
X-bcc: """
pattern = "(?<=(?<!X\S+)To:\s*(?:[^@\s]+@[^\,\s]+,\s*)*?)[^@\s]+@[^\,\s]+"

for match in regex.finditer(pattern, subject):
    print(match.group())
```

**Output**

```
brianherrick@email.msn.com
herriceu2@tdprs.state.tx.us
robertherrick@bankunited.com
kristi.demaiolo@enron.com
suresh.raghavan@enron.com
harry.arora@enron.com
```

**Explanation**

- We have one big lookbehind, then a very basic email matcher: `[^@\s]+@[^\,\s]+` which matches any chars that are not an arrobas or whitespace char, then an arrobas, then any chars that are not a comma or whitespace char (the end-of-email delimiters in your input)
- That email matcher can be replaced by a more sophisticated email regex if need be
- Now to the big lookbehind ``(?<=(?

  The first part `(?<!X-)To:\s*` matches `To:` as long as it is not preceded by `Xsomething`, as asserted by the negative lookbehind `(?<!X-)`

  The non-capture groups `(?:[^@\s]+@[^\,\s]+,\s*)*?` matches as few as needed (the `*?` quantifiers) of the expression `[^@\s]+@[^\,\s]+,\s*` to allow what follows the lookbehind to match. This is an "email skipper" that lets us gradually skip more and more emails with every match

  `[^@\s]+@[^\,\s]+,\s*` is simply a crude email followed by a coma and optional white-space chars (the `\s` matches not only spaces but also carriage returns, tabs etc.)

Comment: Hi, thanx for the suggestion. Would you be able to explain what that regex string does? Especially regarding the lookahead and behind assertions? Would this expression not be compatible with `re`?

Comment: No, it won't work with `re`. The only two engines that will support this are .NET and the `regex` module (two of the top four engines IMO, with PCRE and Perl). For any serious regex in Python you need that module, which is designed to replace `re`. Will add explanation. :)

Comment: Okay, added a long explanation but let me know if something is unclear or you would like more details. :)

Comment: This won't work if you have, say, a `X-Original-To:` header. You'd be better of anchoring to the start of a line; email headers do follow an RFC for a reason. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for the thought, edited the lookbehind to account for it. :) I haven't considered all possibilities for the simple reason that I don't know the details of the standard. Aware that there are other ways to do it, just wanted to put a Python regex solution together to fit the question, and infinite lookbehind is too good to pass up. I am quite sure it enriches the mix of answers, even if it's not the very best way to do it.